# Highlight the background of the navigation menu item currently selected

Tags: android, xml, navigation

this is a snip/screenshot of my app design in Adobe Illustrator: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JIS81.jpg
Depending on the menu you are currently in, the respective section shall be highlighted as shown below (light blue in this case).

I know that you can change the ITEM/ICON color via a custom ThemeOverlay that you create under /styles.xml and by adding app:theme="@style/afore_mentioned_theme_overlay" like this:

```
    <style name="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.navTheme">

    <!-- Color of text and icon when SELECTED -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/color_of_your_choice</item> 

    <!-- Background color when SELECTED -->
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/color_of_your_choice</item> 

</style>
```

However, all this does is change the icon color upon selection, instead of highlighting the section below the icon. 
The main problem is, probably, that the navigation background is a horizontal bar along the entire screen, but I just want to change the color of 33% of it, depending on the selected item. This will probably require a dirty workaround (?).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not that much of a dirty workaround required. Just add this after you initialized your `BottomNavigationView` instance:

```
navigation.setItemBackgroundResource(R.drawable.menubackground);
```

and put this inside `/drawable/menubackground.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/colorAccent" android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@color/colorAccent" android:state_checked="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@color/colorPrimary" />
</selector>
```

Looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you a ton, this is exacly what I was looking for! I can apply the same method for inserting gradient drawables, right?

Comment: Yes, any drawable, I believe.